# Use client default network credentials in WCF service call

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, reporting-services

I have a WCF service that makes a further call to a different service (in this case, the WCF then calls an SSRS Web Service.)  I need to pass through the client's credentials to the WCF, then have the WCF use those credentials.

I am trying to do the following:

```
public ICredentials NetworkCredentials
    {
        get
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_username) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(_password) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(_domain))
                return CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            return new NetworkCredential(_username, _password, _domain);
        }
    }
```

Then using these credentials on the SSRS web service:

```
public SSRS2010ReportServiceConnection(Server server, ICredentials credentials)
    {
        _server = server;
        _service = new ReportingService2010
        {
            Url = server.ServerPath,
            Credentials = credentials
        };
    }
```

However, when this is hosted on an IIS the default, then CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials returns the credentials of the host server rather than the client.

How can I pass through the client's credentials programmatically?

Comment: I think even if it is possible you are looking at a double hop scenario and are going to have to make an AD change to allow that.

Comment: @EricScherrer Thank you for your reply.  That's what I'm afraid of :(

Comment: How do you transmit the credentials to your first service called?

Comment: @Herdo I've tried with windows authentication.  I also have this line when I'm creating the service on the client: service.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

Comment: You could create a new user and dedicate that user for all connections to the reporting service.

Comment: @EricScherrer Yes, that's the workaround and may be the direction we're forced to go, but I'd like to maintain passthrough identity from the client user, so SSRS permissioning remains valid.

Comment: I hear you. When you front ended RS through a web service the byproduct was to move the logical responsibility of authorization to a third thing in your system. Although RS should still do a basic authenticate on its own, the more complex authentication now logically resides above it somewhere, perhaps besides your web service in an engine component. But that's just my opinion, see Clark's fourth law.